# new API for Add-Ins in Outlook 2016 Windows/Mac/Web

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I have written an Outlook Add-In using the "standard" approach, which is a COM Add-In, compatible with Outlook Windows desktop versions.
I'm doing now a research about the capabilities of the new Office API which uses Javascript/HTML and is compatible with Outlook 2016 Windows/Mac and Web.
However, the resources seem really limited, where can I the information what functionalities that API provides i.e. in scope of the Calendar functionality of Outlook?

Comment: Asking for documentation is explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get started using JavaScript APIS using this link : https://dev.outlook.com/MailAppsGettingStarted/GetStarted

API Reference : https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/
This API provides access to mail/calendar item. This APIs are supported in Windows Outlook 2016 and Outlook Web Mail access client.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the functinality is still limited. See https://dev.outlook.com/ for more information about available APIs. But you may also find the EWS helpful. Read more about that in the [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) section.